# send e-mail to confirm data

Tags: windows-phone-7

i would like to send an email that a certain task has been done, to a user's email(i.e. when the user registers for a service, send the email from the phone instead from the server for certain reasons).

How can i send it without having the pop-up with the email appear? i would like to send it automatically so probably i would have to use a more low-level method. i searched the internet and found some indications including this [link that references System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient MailClient but don't know if it is supported in wp7](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/792019-auto-send-email-without-confirmation). Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. A Windows Phone 7 may only send email (or SMS, and make calls) via the framework 'launchers'. This is important for the privacy of the user and overall security of the platform. The only way to support this is from the server. It is highly unlikely that future versions of Windows Phone will support this either.